# How to access Array Object without key name in HTML with Angular

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript

I am developing a web page with Angular 7 and Spring boot 5.

So, using a service, I have this array of arrays :

[image]

And I want to display it in a table in the html component. I don't know how to access each item (for example "Estanteria 2") since it does not have key names.

Is there a way to access this data in html without key names?

Comment: by keys you mean index ? "Estanteria 2" is value at index 3 of the array.
just iterate it and get the values for each index

Comment: I recommend you in the service level treat the data and delivery to the component only a useful data. This way you avoid this kind of problem in the template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will depend on how you want to show it in the view.

You have an array of arrays. So to display `Estanteria 2` in the HTML, something like this will work;

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of array">
  <!-- this will show Estanteria 2 -->
  <div>{{ item[3] }}</div>
</div>
```

If you want to loop through all values in the second array, you could have:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of array">
  <!-- this will show all the values in the second array -->
  <div *ngFor="let value of item">{{ value }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

load the data into a variable `itemList`

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of itemList; let i = index;" >
    <div *ngFor=" let x of item" >{{ x}}</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below,
**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  items = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td *ngFor="let element of item | keyvalue">{{element.value}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```